# Open subtab one after the other in Lightning Service Console using Workspace API

Tags: service-cloud-console, workspaceapi

Is there any limitation of opening multiple subtabs as below using Workspace API? It doesn't throw any error but simply it doesn't open the second subtab for new task while all the console logs get printed. If I move out the second subtab opening logic from `then(function(){})` the subtab opens smoothly but as it would be expected subtab sequence is not guaranteed.

```
workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then(function(tabId) {

    workspaceAPI.openSubtab({       
        url: '/lightning/r/Case/'+result.Id+'/view',
        focus: true
    }).then(function(resp){
        if(followUp) {
            var pageRef = {
                type: "standard__objectPage",
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName: "Task",
                    actionName: "new"
                },
                state: {
                    defaultFieldValues : "WhoId=" + whoId + ",WhatId=" + result.Id 
                }
            };
            console.log('then whoId : ', whoId);
            console.log('then pageRef : ', JSON.stringify(pageRef));
            workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
                pageReference : pageRef,
                focus:true
            });
            console.log('after subtatb');
        }
    });
});
```

(All `followup`, `result.Id` and `whoId` are declared prior to this snippet and all works good).

Comment: your code worked fine for me,how are you triggering this code?

Comment: This snippet is in helper.js and it's triggered upon a button click via controller.js. That code is kind of lengthy and extracted only relevant lines. Any guesses for possible conflicts?